# Datatype for storing pdf in sql table

Tags: c#, sql, pdf

I would like to insert a pdf into a column of a sql table.

I have defined a varbinary(max) datatype for this column.

When I open this pdf in notepad++, it starts with something like this

%PDF-1.6
%äãÏÒ
1 0 obj
[/PDF/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI/Text]
endobj
3 0 obj
<

This doesn't seem to be in binary format.

How can I insert a pdf which looks like the above format in a sql column and of what datatype?

Comment: PDF does look like text, but it must be treated like a binary file, which means that under no circumstances, any character may be altered, added, or removed from the file. This counts in particular for line endings and white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `varchar(max)` to store this.
I've a application and i'm storing with `varchar(max)` and its working fine.

Comment: Hi Lucas, I tried using varchar(max) but it gave me an error -- Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '%PDF-1.6
%äãÏÒ
1 0 obj
[/PDF/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI/Text].... Any ideas?

Comment: I've another table when I store a PDF, and the datatype is "Image" have u tried?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2028857/249690) goes to great lengths about pros and cons of storing binary files in database. And there are the following advice given:

> SQL 2008 has a thing called FILESTREAM which combines
>   both worlds. You upload to the database and it transparently stores
>   the files in a directory on disk. When retrieving you can either pull
>   from the database; or you can go direct to where it lives on the file
>   system.

Comment: Be aware that FILESTREAM requires Windows Integrated Security, this can cause problems when the database is not on the same server and is not part of the same domain. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/04/10/how-it-works-file-streams-requires-integrated-security-windows-authentication/